# Function add_theme_support( 'post-formats') was called incorrectly

Tags: php, wordpress

We are looking to make updates to our website which was put together by an agency last year.

As we are adding new plugins and/or making minor changes to some of the sites using the template and we are getting a number of issues, with this being the most recent.

We have no inhouse development team and limited coding knowledge and are lost as to why this issue is occuring. It seems to be Timber related as that is what is flagged, it is now impacting all of the sites (multisite template) even though no changes have been made there.

I suspect it is conflicting with the new plugins in some way but cannot figure out why?

Can anyone assist, I am sure it is probably something glaringly obvious but gioven the lack of knowledge on these things inteh company it is very much out of our ability.

Big thing atm is it has brought an error message on headers on the live Cairn sites that we are not working on. This is a big issue so any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Jonathan @ Cairn Hotel Group.

Comment: The footer is showing a different error message Notice: ob_end_flush(): failed to send buffer of zlib output compression (0) in /home/cairncollection/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5275

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: WP_Error::$name in /home/cairncollection/public_html/wp-content/themes/mw-cairncollection/lib/timber.php on line 37

Notice: Undefined index: footer_nav in /home/cairncollection/public_html/wp-content/themes/mw-cairncollection/lib/timber.php on line 46

Comment: In a multi site environment, changes to plugins/themes/core affect all sites, and as such they need to be done carefully. Unfortunately, without knowing the specific changes you’ve made we can’t debug much deeper. My recommendation is to undo or restore from an older working version of the site, if possible. You can also turn off WP_DEBUG for now to at least hide those notices.

Comment: Thank you for this, that is a good place to start. 
What additional details would you need to assist with a debug? I can provide them as I work back through all the changes we have made. 

Thanks,
jonny

Comment: You really might want to tap a professional developer for this. [Debugging](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) WordPress actions is a little bit of an advanced topic that isn’t easy to explain fully because sometimes you have to temporarily hack things to see what is doing what. Also, the way Timber was installed, although not necessarily wrong, doesn’t follow the ways I’m familiar with, and the line number of your error doesn’t match anything that I’d expect.

Comment: Hi, I have the WP-Error log here that has the specific issues it has flagged. 
Would it help if I attached that @ChrisHaas